# solarized color-scheme alsamixer

Tags: arch-linux

So I just changed my terminal(termite) color-theme to solarized(light) but it seems that it won't affect `alsamixer`. I would like to have a light background.
I changed the config of `termite` and `.Xresources` to the solarized color-theme...

[image]

Comment: Some of cmd program when are being started they initliaze color , so they don't inherit thems-color.

Comment: so why the -1? dumb question?

Comment: I didn't vote down.

Comment: I didn't meant you, general Question ;-)

Comment: I suggesst read carefuly http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `alsamixer` activly sets its background colour to black. In terms of [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) this means it sends the `^[[40m` sequence. You can verify this by fiddling with its output:

1. Run `alsamixer` while redirecting its output to a file:

   ```
   $ alsamixer > alsamixer.ansi
   ```

   Use <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to exit. You can also use

   ```
   $ alsamixer | tee alsamixer.ansi
   ```

   if you want to see the output at the same time.
2. Strip the offending parts:

   ```
   $ sed -r -e 's/^[\[40m//g' -e 's/^[\[H^[\[2J.{,80}$//' < am.ansi
   ```

   the firs regexp removes the black background while the latter removes the sequence for clearing the screen upon exit. Note that `^[` is actually a single ESC character, in terminal usually produced by <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>. The last alsamixer screen should now be displayed with your default background.

You can also try chaining it:

```
    $ alsamixer | sed -u 's/^[\[40m//g'
```

which in some cases might show you the alsamixer from time to time - the problem here is, that the output produced is one line and thus `sed` only starts processing it once its internal buffer fills enough. Thus you can forget about interactivity.

As to your question: fix is either a recompile or a filter that would remove the sequences with minimal buffering.